# Textarea width does not align with the containing div

Tags: html, css, xhtml

i am wondering why the textarea refuses to stay aligned with the containing div?

```
<!-- the textarea pokes out-->
<div style="border:1px solid #ccc; width:300px">
  <textarea style="width:100%"></textarea>
</div>
```

It is causing me difficulty in ensuring alignment of elements

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default, a `<textarea>` element is rendered with a border around it. The problem with this is that when you set the `width` property on an element, you're only setting the content width, not the total width. The total width of the element is (width + border + padding + margin) so when you set the `width` on the `<textarea>` to be 100% it sets the *content width* to 300px but the total width is that 300px plus the default borders, which causes it to exceed the 300px width of the `<div>`.

You'll could accommodate these borders in the `<div>` using padding/margins, but a better solution would be to set the `box-sizing` property on the `<textarea>` to `border-box` to force the `width` property to define the total width of everything up to and including the border of the element.

You'll need to do a bit of research on that property because it's declared differently in all browsers (e.g. `-moz-box-sizing`, `-ms-box-sizing`, `-webkit-box-sizing`, etc.). [Here is the QuirksMode page on `box-sizing`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html) for you to look through.

The `box-sizing` fix works for Firefox, but I haven't tested it in other browsers. It's possible that some of them, particularly when in quirks/legacy mode, could also apply a margin to the element. If this is the case, then all you would need to do would be to remove the margins with CSS (AFAIK, there isn't a widely supported option for `box-sizing` that extends to margins - only ones for content, padding, and border).

I'd suggest being specific with this fix, and only removing the left/right margins (i.e. `margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0;`) rather than removing margins entirely (i.e. `margin: 0;`) to preserve any top/bottom margins if they exist (and if you want to keep them). I know Firefox applies a 1px margin to the top/bottom, and other browsers might as well.

Comment: What an excellent answer. Thank you. This answers my question perfectly

Comment: what a patience to write such explanation , thanks +1 for you

Comment: @gov - thanks, but it wasn't patience so much as bullheaded perfectionism. You can only see three revisions in the answer history, but there were a bunch of minor edits and things in there that don't get picked up.

Answer (score 0):

I tried that in Firefox, Chrome and IE, and they all show it properly. I suspect that you DIV is inside of another container and that's causing the problem.

Please add a part of your code.

Comment: I managed to reproduce the problem in FF 3.6. See my answer for details.

Comment: I think you're testing in quirks mode. Add a doctype like `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the top of your test page to force the browser into standards mode and you'll see the problem clear as day.

Answer (score 0):

The textarea may have a margin being applied to it.  Try this:

```
<div style="border:1px solid #ccc; width:300px">
  <textarea style="width:100%; margin: 0;"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: According to FireBug, the problem is borders, not margins. See my answer for details.

Comment: Good call.  Good answer, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="border:1px solid #ccc; width:300px">
  <textarea style="width:100%"></textarea>
</div>
```

Tested working on Firefox 3.6.10, Internet Explorer 8 and Google Chrome.

But, maybe instead of enclosing it in a DIV, you can also try this:

```
<textarea style="border:1px solid #ccc; width:300px"></textarea>
```

Which about has the same looks as your original code.

Comment: I think you'll find that you're testing in quirks mode, not standards mode. It works fine for me in quirks mode as well, but breaks in standards mode.

Comment: Excuse me if I sound stupid, but, I still can't grasp the differences between quirks mode and standards mode, yes, I've read the Wikipedia article, may you provide a brief explanantion?

Comment: @rao i just realized that there are 2 different modes too! =D

Comment: @Nareshkumar Rao: Back in the old days of the internet, many moons ago, browsers came up with their own implementations of how certain things should act (this is still done today, and drives new browser/html features moreso than the W3C does) but they often differed from one another. The W3C and standards came along and tried to set things right, but there was still an awful lot of mangled HTML code out on the internet that, based on the standards, was incorrect. Browsers developed "quirks modes" so that relied on browser bugs would still work.

Comment: @Nareshkumar Rao: [con't] Nowadays, browsers mostly try to render things according to the standards. This is what we call "standards mode" and is triggered when the browser encounters a DOCTYPE at the top of the HTML. If the DOCTYPE is missing, the browser assumes it's an old page, and tries to render it against the old (non-)rules. We call this "quirks mode." You can check which mode you're in via javascript. The `document.compatType` tells you which mode you're in. A value of `CSS1Compat` means you're in standards mode, and the value `BackCompat` means you're in quirks mode.

Comment: @ming yeow: I just wrote two comments to @Nareshkumar Rao about standards/quirks mode. I'm leaving this comment for you because StackOverflow only notifies one @username per comment.